# Recover value set by memset

Tags: c, memset

How could I recover the value of a memset?

In the following code, the program is supposed to allocate a certain amount of space requested by the user and store the size the user requested ahead of the pointer returned to the user:

```
void* my_malloc(size_t sz)
    void* block = malloc(sz + sizeof(size_t));
    void* retval = &block + sizeof(size_t);
    memset(block, sz, sizeof(size_t));
return retval;
```

In another function, the user can pass in the pointer of their data and I want to recover the size that I stored ahead of their memory.

```
void my_free(void *ptr) {

    void* block = ptr - sizeof(size_t);
    size_t *sz;
    memset(sz, block, sizeof(size_t));//This is the line in question.

free(block);
```

Is there any kind of memread function I can use the reset the value of sz?  This current method is giving me errors

Comment: I don't think your call to `memset()` does what you think it does. From what you've described, you don't want to use `memset()` at all.

Comment: In addition to using `memset` incorrectly, your computation of `retval` in `my_malloc` is also completely bogus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to read the documentation of `memset`. It sets a block of memory to have *all bytes the same*.  The effect of `memset(block, sz, sizeof(size_t))` is to set the first `8` (or whatever the size of `size_t` is) bytes of `block` to all be `(unsigned char)sz` .

To copy some bytes the correct function is `memcpy`, so that line should be:

```
memcpy(block, &sz, sizeof sz);
```

In the `free` function you want:

```
size_t sz;
memcpy(&sz, block, sizeof sz);
```

Also, you do incorrect pointer arithmetic in two places:

```
void *retval = &block + sizeof(size_t);    // moves sizeof(size_t) * sizeof(void *) bytes
void *block = ptr - sizeof(size_t);        // illegal
```

The definition of pointer arithmetic is to move by *that number of elements of the type being pointed to*.  You seem to be assuming it is the number of bytes.  What you really want, respectively, is:

```
void *retval = (char *)block + sizeof(size_t);
void *block = (char *)ptr - sizeof(size_t);
```

The cast is because pointer arithmetic is not defined for `void *`. Since `sizeof(char) == 1` then doing pointer arithmetic on a `char *` moves you by that number of bytes.

If you understand the pointer arithmetic correctly then you will realize that another way to write those statements is:

```
void *retval = (size_t *)block + 1;
void *block = (size_t *)ptr - 1;
```

Finally your malloc replacement will fail for any type that has a greater alignment requirement than `size_t` (although it's likely that your system doesn't have any such types).